# How to delete partiton data in dolphindb

Tags: dolphindb

In DolphinDB, I have a distributed database that partitions by date and stock code.  I want to delete the data from the past week. I found that the function dropPartition  can do this, but it can only delete the leaf partition, not the top partition directly, so how can I clean up the data distributed on the cluster machines last week?

Answer (score 1):

When using COMPO partition by date and stock code, you can drop partition by date as follows

```
db1= database(,VALUE,2007.08.01..2007.08.30)    
db2=database(, VALUE,  symbol(`A`B`C`D`E))  
db = database(dbPath, COMPO, [db1,db2])
dropPartition(db,[2007.08.01,2007.08.02],,true)
```